# JUnit test cases for date class

Tags: java, eclipse, testing

I am new to writing JUnit test cases. Below is my class:

```
public class DateTime {

    public static void main(String[] args) {         
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd, HH:mm:ss");
        //get current date time with Date()
        Date date = new Date();
        System.out.println("Date,Time:"+dateFormat.format(date));
    }
}
```

How can i write test cases for this class and how many?

Comment: It's hard to write tests for code which: a) writes to System.out; b) depends on the current date/time; c) depends on the current locale. I suggest that you start off with code which is more amenable to testing...

Comment: Why do you want to test classes from the JDK? You are barely doing anything inside your main method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can not tell you how to test your own code. That is up to you. But a simple google search gives many [jUnit](http://www.vogella.com/articles/JUnit/article.html) tutorials. And how many tests for each class depends on how thoroughly you want to test your code, but once again, it is up to you.

However in this example, you are doing nothing that isn't strictly provided by Java, so there really is no need to test what is native to the language. You want to test functionality you write, not the JDK.